# Why are these CSS properties not inherited in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

My HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__side--front">
    VORNE FRONT
  </div>
  <div class="card__side--back">
     HINTEN BACK
  </div>                            
</div>
```

My SASS:

```
.card{
    // Perspetive
    // https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/
    perspective: 150rem;
    -moz-prespective:150rem;
    &__side{
         color:#fff;
         font-size: 3rem;
         height: 50rem;
         transition:all .8s;
    &--front {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    &--back {
        background-color: green;
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
&:hover &__side--back{
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
}   
&:hover &__side--front{
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
 } 
}
```

I assumed that the properties of e.g. color,height and font-size is inherited from
.card__side{} to .card__side--front{}

But it won't?

Does anyone know why?

Comment: and where is card__side in your HTML code?

Comment: Thank You... My mistake was to forget this classes in HTML